# Find subspace $T$ such that $\mathbb{M}_{2\times 3}^{\mathbb{R}}=W\oplus T$

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I have a question in which I find a base for $W$, which is $\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 &1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 &0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right \}$.
Later on in the question, I'm asked to find a subspace  $T$ such that $\mathbb{M}_{2\times 3}^{\mathbb{R}}=W \oplus T$.

I'm *clueless* of what I am supposed to do, I know $\dim T=4$ and that $T\cap W=\left \{ 0 \right \}$. But that doesn't assist me much.

Comment: Had the two elements been $[1 \ 1 \ 1 \ 1 \ 2 \ 3]$ and $[0 \ \mbox{-1} \  0\  1\  0\  0]$ in $X=\Bbb{R}^6$ would you know how to find a complement in $X$? It's the same here

Comment: If I understand your direction, I don't think that the level of this question is leading us to orthogonality since we aren't supposed to know that yet.

If that wasn't what you're saying I'd like you to elaborate please.

Comment: Orthogonality is not an issue. You have to find 4 other vectors in $X$ which together with the two given form a base for $X$. (and it's very simple to find!)

Comment: Uhm not simple at all? I don't seem to find a systematic way of doing so without guessing. Moreover how would you know that those 4 acutally span a space such that it's $X$ is the sum of the two spaces?

Comment: You may take e.g. $[ 0\ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]$, $[ 0\ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0]$, $[ 0\ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0]$, $[ 0\ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1]$. Together with the first two they form a base e.g. because all together they yield a triangular matrix with non-zero elements on the diagonal. But true, it is a bit of guessing. A more systematic way is to put given vectors into a matrix and do row reductions.

Comment: Ah I see. And because they're a basis then every vector in $X$ is written in a unique way as a linear combination of the terms in the basis, which yields a unique sum of a linear combination from $T$ and a linear combination from $W$. hence the sum is a direct sum?

Comment: Exactly ! And as you see, there is a lot of freedom in the choices.